# PagerView overlapping PagerTabStrip / PagerTitleStrip

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-viewpager, android-view

I've been trying for about a week to get my PagerView not to overlap the TitleStrip.

I've tried absolutely everything I can think of, and one StackOverflow question that looked like the same question, had an answer that wasn't applicable.

It appears that both the PagerTitleStrip and the TextView start at 0,0 (left,top)

Any help would be appreciated. Note that I can't use any XML (inc Layout.xml) so it's all done programatically.

**Here's a full working example of my problem:**

```
package com.example.projname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        PagerTabStrip myPagerTabStrip = new PagerTabStrip(this);
        myPagerTabStrip.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
        ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        viewPager.addView(myPagerTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
        setContentView(viewPager);
    }

    class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        public final String[] Titles = {
            "Title One",
            "Title Two",
            "Title Three",
            "Title Four",
            "Title Five"
        };

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Titles.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return (view == object);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return Titles[position];
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            String myString = new String("Page " + (position + 1) + "\r\n");
            textView.setText(myString + myString + myString + myString + myString + myString);
            container.addView(textView);
            return textView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit1: Adding a screenshot of the problem:**
[image: The text Page1 is shown much higher than it should be]

**Edit2: Updating question with answer (in-case anyone tries this in the future**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    layoutParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    PagerTabStrip myPagerTabStrip = new PagerTabStrip(this);
    MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();       
    ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    viewPager.addView(myPagerTabStrip, layoutParams);
    viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
    setContentView(viewPager);
}
```

Comment: In general, answers don't belong in questions--I'd suggest either adding your own answer, or editing the accepted answer to include the actual solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that I can't use any XML

Why?

> Any help would be appreciated.

Try a version of `addView()` that takes a `LayoutParams` object as a parameter, and use an instance of `ViewPager.LayoutParams`. Also, use the `gravity` field on the `ViewPager.LayoutParams` instead of `setGravity()`.

If that does not help, temporarily set up a `ViewPager` and `PagerTitleStrip` in XML (e.g., in a separate project) and examine the results in Hierarchy View to see how the XML approach constructs matters, so you can try to replicate it.

Comment: I tried setting up a ViewPager and PagerTitleStrip in XML, but I could not see any differences other than the mPrivateFlags ONLY_DRAWS_BACKGROUND and OPAQUE_BACKGROUND. Changing the OPAQUE_BACKGROUND flag by using .setAlpha(1f) didn't change anything, and I'm unsure how to change ONLY_DRAWS_BACKGROUND flag to 1 (as the XML does), although I wonder if this is just a temporary flag.

Comment: @user1256169: I am rather confident it has nothing to do with backgrounds. You also neglected to explain why you are not taking the simple solution of setting this up using an XML layout source.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for me to use XML as most of my views are created dynamically (my application does not even have a res/layout folder at the moment.
Surely there must be a simple way for this to work, I have to be overlooking something. I'm going to try half in XML, half programatically, so that I can determine if it's the container (ViewPager) or the PagerTabStrip (I should note that the same happens when using PagerTitleStrip)

Comment: @user1256169: "It doesn't make sense for me to use XML as most of my views are created dynamically" -- you are certainly welcome to do that. Do not expect much help with that technique, though, because a very tiny percentage of Android developers take this approach.

Comment: That's a fair call, but I am narrowing down the problem. Looks like you might have been pretty spot on with the first suggestion. if I use the XML layout, then remove the view using viewPager.removeAllViews(), then re-add it using the same addView(...) I have the same issue.

So now to try and do as you indicated above.

Comment: You were spot on. Using AddView with LayoutParams (with Gravity set) solved my dilemma.
**Thank you @CommonsWare**

-Updating question to indicate answer for other readers.